# How to interpret mean squared error matrix in the context of multiple time series?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, covariance-matrix, vector-autoregression, multivariate-regression

Consider the time series of 2 variables $x_1$ and $x_2$, put together $y=(x_1,x_2)$:
$$
y_t = \begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\ v_2
\end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix}
c & d\\ 
e & f
\end{bmatrix}y_{t-1} + u_t.
$$

The fixed, nonsingular covaraince matrix is: $\Sigma_u = \begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1^{2} & 0\\ 
0 & \sigma_2^{2} \end{bmatrix}$.

The mean squared error matrix of the 1-step ahead forecasts is hence also:
$\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1^{2} & 0\\ 
0 & \sigma_2^{2} \end{bmatrix}$.

How should I interpret this mean squared error matrix?

Comment: I think I need to read up a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the name it should be 
\begin{aligned}
&\mathbb{E} \begin{bmatrix}
\varepsilon_1^2 & \varepsilon_1 \varepsilon_2\\ 
\varepsilon_2 \varepsilon_1 & \varepsilon_2^2 
\end{bmatrix} \\
= \ &\mathbb{E}\begin{bmatrix}
(x_{1,t+1}-\hat x_{1,t+1|t})^2 & (x_{1,t+1}-\hat x_{1,t+1|t})(x_{2,t+1}-\hat x_{2,t+1|t})\\ 
(x_{2,t+1}-\hat x_{2,t+1|t})(x_{1,t+1}-\hat x_{1,t+1|t}) & (x_{2,t+1}-\hat x_{2,t+1|t})^2 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
where $\hat x_{i,t+1|t}$ is the forecast of $x_{i,t+1}$ made at time $t$, and  $\varepsilon_i$ is the forecast error of $x_i$ (the random variable, not the realization) for $i=\{1,2\}$.